# Select a unique name from Users that have more than 5 titles. SQL

Tags: sql, select, h2

DB is H2(in-memory).

There are two tables: 
*Users* with *id, name, surname*. And *Documents* with *id, title, text, user_id*.

*user_id*  is a foreign key from *Users id*.

The task is: 
Select a unique name from Users that have more than 5 titles.

I created this select, but it gives an error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.name, documents.user_id,
                 ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM documents AS d
                   WHERE d.user_id = documents.user_id
                     )
                     AS rn
FROM documents, users WHERE users.id = documents.user_id
GROUP BY documents.user_id AND users.name having rn > 5 ORDER BY documents.user_id, users.name, rn;
```

Error: **[22018][22018] Data conversion error converting "Douglas"; SQL statement: SELECT DISTINCT users.name, documents.user_id, ( SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) FROM documents AS d WHERE d.user_id = documents.user_id ...**

(Douglas is a first row name from a table)

Help me to resolve this problem, and find a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GROUP BY documents.user_id AND users.name
```

SQL is trying to resolve the boolean expression `documents.user_id AND users.name` and cannot reconcile what `integer and string` is supposed to be.

Separate multiple columns in a group by with a comma.

```
group by documents.user_id, users.name
```